# datetime.datetime.strptime not present in Python 2.4.1

Tags: python, datetime

Our team is required to use Python 2.4.1 in certain circumstances. `strptime` is not present in the `datetime.datetime` module in Python 2.4.1:

```
Python 2.4.1 (#65, Mar 30 2005, 09:13:57) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

As opposed to in 2.6:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime
<built-in method strptime of type object at 0x1E1EF898>
```

While typing this up, I found it in the time module of 2.4.1:

```
Python 2.4.1 (#65, Mar 30 2005, 09:16:17) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime
<built-in function strptime>
```

I take it that `strptime` moved at some point?  What's the best way to check things like this.  I tried looking through python's release history but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that `strptime` is still in the `time` module, even as of 2.7.1, as well as in `datetime`.

If, however, you look at the [documentation for datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) in a recent version, you will see this under `strptime`:

> This is equivalent to `datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))`

so you can use that expression instead. Note that the same entry also says "New in version 2.5".

Comment: That explains everything - I thought I checked the documentation to see if it mentioned when this was introduced, but I clearly missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem as well.

Based on Daniel's answer, this works for me when you're not sure under which Python version (2.4 vs 2.6) the script will be running:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

if hasattr(datetime, 'strptime'):
    #python 2.6
    strptime = datetime.strptime
else:
    #python 2.4 equivalent
    strptime = lambda date_string, format: datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))

print strptime("2011-08-28 13:10:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

-Fi

Answer (score 1):

new methods are usually documented in the Library reference with "News since version...."
I can not remember that methods have disappeared or were removed...which would be a backward compatibility foul. Methods subject to removal are usually official deprecated with a DeprecationWarning.