# How to increment an integer day by 5 days in python

Tags: python, linux, date

Very new to python, please excuse the noob question:

I have a number that represents a date like :

```
date = 20121228
```

( representing December 28th, 2012)

How can I increment that date by 5 days in python so I end up with a new (correct) number representing the date like

```
date = 20130102
```

I don't want:

```
date = 20121233
```

Update: When I try and use `datetime.strptime` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
date = 20121228
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y%m%d").date() + timedelta(days=5)
print datetime.strftime(dt, "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: I've found examples with that as well but I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Are you using Python version at least 2.5?

Comment: No that's my problem, but I found a good solution and explanation to that here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585706/datetime-datetime-strptime-not-present-in-python-2-4-1  I need to use time.strptime and your answer should work great, thanks!

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to, you really should update to a more recent version of Python to get this and other functionality. Otherwise you'll keep running into problems where code examples may not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it to a `datetime.date()` object, add 5 days, then reformat back to your number:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y%m%d').date()
dt += timedelta(days=5)
date = int(dt.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> date = 20121228
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y%m%d').date()
>>> dt += timedelta(days=5)
>>> int(dt.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
20130102
```

For Python versions before Python 2.5, you'll need to use the `time.strptime()` version:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime(*(time.strptime(str(date), '%Y%m%d')[:6]))
dt += timedelta(days=5)
date = int(dt.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

Comment: I think this because I'm on an older version of python I don't seem to have strptime under datetime

Comment: @sputn1ck: Did you `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`? I used the latter. The method was added in Python 2.5 (quite old now).

Comment: time.strptime is what I ended up needing to import (I'm on an old old version) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert your date into a string first. Then use a `timedelta` object to add the days to the `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.strptime(str(20121228), "%Y%m%d")
print (d + timedelta(days=5)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
```