# Display given datetime in reverse order in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.4

I have a date timestamp like "2013-12-20 23:40:33". Now, my requirement is to re-format this date in reverse order like :

```
<seconds><minutes><hr><day><month><year>
```

in python. Please suggest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the string into a `datetime` object with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and format to string with [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%S:%M:%H %d-%m-%Y')
'33:40:23 20-12-2013'
```

Comment: strptime is not supported in my python version. This is the error : AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: @SaikatDasgupta python 2.4? Take a look at the workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585706/datetime-datetime-strptime-not-present-in-python-2-4-1.

Comment: @SaikatDasgupta but you really need to upgrade your Python - 2.4 is  becoming 10 years old this year..

Comment: Yes alec I agree... But this not any serious project.. Am trying out few alternatives using python.. that's it.. Thanks a lot for your assistance on this. I will try out and let you know :)

Comment: time.strftime("%S%M%H%d%m%y20",time.strptime('2013-12-20 23:40:33', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).. This works fine :)

Comment: I have one more problem like... I have a group of numbers say.. 123 , 89 , 46 and so on... Now, I want to format these strings together ( add padding bits ) in one line as in bash it works perfectly... printf "%08X" 123 89 46 = 0000007B000000590000002E... Now how do I accomplish the same thing in python

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-12-20 23:40:33', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%S:%M:%H %d-%m-%Y')
'33:40:23 20-12-2013'
```

Comment: strptime is not supported in my python version. This is the error : AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to validate the time string:

```
>>> import re
>>> '<%s>' % '><'.join(re.findall(r'\d+', "2013-12-20 23:40:33")[::-1])
'<33><40><23><20><12><2013>'
```

It is 6 times faster than the corresponding `datetime` solution:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("2013-12-20 23:40:33", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('<%S><%M><%H><%d><%m><%Y>')
'<33><40><23><20><12><2013>'
```

Or 5 times faster than [`time` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758625/display-given-datetime-in-reverse-order-in-python/28761852#comment45798437_28758678):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('<%S><%M><%H><%d><%m><%Y>', time.strptime("2013-12-20 23:40:33", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
'<33><40><23><20><12><2013>'
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. This worked perfectly. I have one more problem like... I have a group of numbers say.. 123 , 89 , 46 and so on... Now, I want to format these strings together ( add padding bits ) in one line as in bash it works perfectly... printf "%08X" 123 89 46 = 0000007B000000590000002E... Now how do I accomplish the same thing in python

Comment: It is almost the same. But the specifics depend on how the number are represented in your program: is it a list, or a tuple? Is the length fixed? You could ask a separate question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
d = "2013-12-20 23:40:33"  
date = d[17]+d[18]+":"+d[14]+d[15]+":"+d[11]+d[12]+" "+d[8]+d[9]+"-"+d[5]+d[6]+"-"+d[0]+d[1]+d[2]+d[3]  
print(d)  
print(date)
```